# MVC5 bundle url version and content are missing

Tags: javascript, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, web-deployment, bundling-and-minification

In my MVC5 web application I use two bundles for a page, one contains the common JavaScript files for all the pages and the other bundle is specific for the page. This works fine in development environment but the page specific bundle does not load in the staging. The Rendered script tags are as below.

```
<script src="/bundles/jsAll?v=72eJMPeVrT1mvbZw1VAU7y6r7vodOImt5NOMq4Gcp581"></script>    
<script src="/bundles/my-page?v="></script>
```

Could not figure out why this happens...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was locally this works because all the files are available, but did not work after deployment because the script file was not included to the project, hence the file does not get deployed to the destination. Since the file is missing the bundle has nothing to serve, so there won't be a version nor content.