# Bundling in Azure is not working for bootstrap and jquery, ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, azure

I'm trying to publish my ASP.NET MVC application in Azure, and I have a big problem. For some reason, Bootstrap an jQuery aren't uploading in the cloud and as the result I have this in my `<head>`

```
<link href="/bundle/css?v=M0YDCkvF0TWb7qBimSKIIQStPqLp2LPc1kQmD4tJabM1" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/bundles/jquery?v="></script>
<script src="/bundles/modernizr?v="></script>
```

CSS bundle includes only content of "site.css", so bundling actually works, but libraries are missing for some reason.

Same configuration works absolutely fine in local IIS (including `<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />`), so I think the problem should be in the uploading configuration, or files just disappears for some reason. Please, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looks like I've figured it out. After one more day I found this question [MVC5 bundle url version and content are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669509/mvc5-bundle-url-version-and-content-are-missing) and its answer helped me a lot. For some reason in my .csproj file all bootstrap and jquery files were included as `<None Include="...">`. I've replaced it with `<Content Include="...">` and now it works.